# validate form with javascript doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form to change password, with javascript validate check for all the form fields, however, I don't think the Javascript even gets triggered. Entering submit takes me straight to Null Pointer Exception error in my Controller. Am I missing something ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Change Password Page</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(){

            var username=document.form.j_username.value;
            var oldPassword=document.form.j_old_password.value;
            var newPassword=document.form.j_new_password.value;
            var confirmPassword=document.form.j_confirm_password.value;

            if(username==""){
             alert("Enter Username!");
              return false;
                }

            if(oldPassword==""){
             alert("Enter Old Password!");
              return false;
                }

            if(newPassword==""){
                 alert("Enter New Password!");
                  return false;
                }

            if(confirmPassword==""){
                 alert("Enter Confirm Password!");
                  return false;
                }

            return true;

        }       
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="change_password-header">
    <h1>Blah Blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="L" style="float: left; left; padding: 1em; background-color: #8eb4e3; border: 1px solid black;">
    <form action="changepassword" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <p><strong style="color: #e3f7ff">Username: </strong>
            &nbsp;<input type="text" name="j_username" size="25" />
        </p>

        <p><strong style="color: #e3f7ff">Old Password: </strong>
            &nbsp;<input type="password" size="25" name="j_old_password" />
        </p>

        <p><strong style="color: #e3f7ff">New Password: </strong>
            &nbsp;<input type="password" size="25" name="j_new_password" />
        </p>

        <p><strong style="color: #e3f7ff">Confirm New Password: </strong>
            &nbsp;<input type="password" size="25" name="j_confirm_password" />
        </p>

        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button-login" style="background-color: #c7d9f1; border: 1px solid black;" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button-login" style="background-color: #c7d9f1; border: 1px solid black;"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; padding: 0 0 0 2em" class="change_password-footer">
        <div><a href = "login">Return back to login screen</a></div>
        <br/>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code reeks of bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to name your form:

```
<form action="changepassword" name="test" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

and reference in JS like this:

```
var username=document.forms.test.j_username.value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gq79y/

Comment: Naming the form does not help in his case. There is only one form in the page anyways so the code should work fine..